# CSS broken with Bootstrap + Github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I see some weird behavior of my Bootstrap + Github Pages website: http://grigory.us

Sometimes the CSS is broken (like now), e.g. you can see all the lists going horizontally and text in them going vertically instead of the other way round. Also, the colors are not displayed properly and some of the elements are shifted. Locally everything looks fine and sometimes the online version looks fine too, e.g. I've seen it broken once before but then it was fine again.

I will greatly appreciate any suggestions that might help fix this.

Comment: can't load :`http://grigory.us/starter-template.css`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with neo, `starter-template.css` is not loading. Using Firebug, you can see this (below) which means that it is failing to load.
[image: FirebugScreenGrab]

Answer (score 0):

I see this error.

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://grigory.us/starter-template.css".
```

Indeed its response is html...